# how to get the index of thrust foreach

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to using thrust for each to give device vector certain values
here is the code

```
const uint N = 222222; 
struct assign_functor
{
  template <typename Tuple>
  __device__ 
  void operator()(Tuple t)
  {  
    uint x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    uint y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    uint offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; 

    thrust::get<0>(t) = offset; 
  }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 

  thrust::device_vector <float> d_float_vec(N);  

  thrust::for_each(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
      thrust::make_tuple(d_float_vec.begin()) 
    ), 
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
      thrust::make_tuple(d_float_vec.end())
    ), 
    assign_functor()
  );

  std::cout<<d_float_vec[10]<<" "<<d_float_vec[N-2] 
}
```

the output of d_float_vec[N-2] is supposed to be 222220; but it turns out 1036. whats wrong with my code??

I know I could use thrust::sequence to give a sequence values to the vector. I just want to know how to get the real index for thrust foreach function. Thanks!

Comment: Why should the output be N-2?

Comment: uint x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    uint y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    uint offset = x + y * blockDim.x * gridDim.x; offset is the index . I want each vector has its own index

Comment: Yes, but you are implicitly assuming that the every thread processes exactly 1 output point in the array, and there is a direct relationship between the 2D thread index you calculate and a position in the array. Neither of those things are necessarily true.

Comment: Neither of those things are necessarily true? whats the mechanism of thrust foreach? how to get index for each vector using for each? I tried thrust::get<0>(t) = t, but fail to complile;

Comment: The mechanism is an undefined implementation detail. It might be different on different architectures and in different thrust versions. If you want an index, use a counting iterator

Comment: Thanks, but how to use  counting iterator in my case. I read the thrust document but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in comments, your approach is never likely to work because you have assumed a number of things about the way `thrust::for_each` works internally which are probably not true, including:

- You implicitly are assuming that `for_each` uses a single thread to process each input element. This is almost certainly not the case; it is much more likely that thrust will process multiple elements per thread during the operation.
- You are also assuming that execution happens in order so that the Nth thread processes the Nth array element. That may not be the case, and execution may occur in an order which cannot be known *a priori*
- You are assuming `for_each` processes the whole input data set in a single kernel laumch

Thrust algorithms should be treated as black boxes whose internal operations are undefined and no knowledge of them is required to implement user defined functors. In your example, if you require a sequential index inside a functor, pass a counting iterator. One way to re-write your example would be like this:

```
#include "thrust/device_vector.h"
#include "thrust/for_each.h"
#include "thrust/tuple.h"
#include "thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h"

typedef unsigned int uint;
const uint N = 222222; 
struct assign_functor
{
  template <typename Tuple>
  __device__ 
  void operator()(Tuple t)
  {  
    thrust::get<1>(t) = (float)thrust::get<0>(t);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  thrust::device_vector <float> d_float_vec(N);  
  thrust::counting_iterator<uint> first(0);
  thrust::counting_iterator<uint> last = first + N;

  thrust::for_each(
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
      thrust::make_tuple(first, d_float_vec.begin()) 
    ), 
    thrust::make_zip_iterator( 
      thrust::make_tuple(last, d_float_vec.end())
    ), 
    assign_functor()
  );

  std::cout<<d_float_vec[10]<<" "<<d_float_vec[N-2]<<std::endl; 
}
```

Here the counting iterator gets passed in a tuple along with the data array, allow the functor access to a sequential index which corresponds to the data array entry it is dealing with.